# Local development with multiple local packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I have a NodeJS app and several local packages(some utilities that I want to share with other browser apps) all written in Typescript with the following structure:

**Package A** (this has some basic utility functions)

- *no dependencies*

**Package B**  (this uses the utility functions to do something more complex)

- package A  <- with npm link

**NodeJS app** (I need to use both the basic utility functions and the complex ones)

- package B <- with npm link
- package A <- with npm link

All of these packages have been built to their .js equivalents but I get an error when I'm trying to use a method from package A inside my NodeJS app.

For example:

Package A/Collections.ts:

```
class Collection{
    count(){ ...code here }
}
```

Package B/ComplexCollections.ts:

```
import Collection from "project-a/Collection";

class ComplexCollection extends Collection{
}
```

NodeJS app/index.ts:

```
import ComplexCollection from "project-B/ComplexCollection";

const collection = new ComplexCollection();
colection.count() // this gives `error TS2339: Property 'count' does not exist on type 'ComplexCollection'`
```

It seems that package B doesn't expose the package's A Collection class.

I can fix this error by using directly the .ts files but as far as I know, it is not a good practice as per [this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8284#issuecomment-341417325)

How can I fix this issue? 
Or what is a good local development workflow with this kind of setup?

My final plan is to use these packages inside web apps built with angular, react, vue or vanilla JS (through webpack)